# Try to prevent link to redirect with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am writing an event that when user click a link, a payload of data will be sent to server, and callback with a function redirecting to another page.

Here the problem: I cant stop link to be redirect too early until the XHR are successfully made. I put `return false` at the end of event but it doesnt work.

Note that if I use JQuery verison, it works pretty well. But not with JS vanilla.

Please help me with this case. Thank in advance!

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('class');

if (button[0] != undefined) {
    button[0].addEventListener("click", submitDataDemo);
}

function submitDataDemo() {

    ``
    `
    get and format the data
    `
    ``


    var sendDataRequest2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    sendDataRequest2.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            window.location.href = 'The success page';
        }
    };
    sendDataRequest2.open('POST',
        'server',
        true);
    sendDataRequest2.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    sendDataRequest2.send(payLoad);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Use a `<button type=button>` instead of an `<a>`

Comment: the "button" actually a <div class="class">. I can't edit the source code :(

Comment: Update 1: I rolled back to my jQuery version and wait for answer for JS vanila case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `preventDefault`:

```js
function submitDataDemo(event) {
  event.preventDefault()

  // ...rest of function
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: It still doesnt works. error log: "preventDefault() is not a property"

Comment: I also not working with me

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, but still can't understand why `return false` doesn't work.

Using `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` on the handler will stop the link redirecting me because the parent element has a event click too!

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('class');

if (button[0] != undefined) {
    button[0].addEventListener("click", submitDataDemo);
}

function submitDataDemo(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    // .. function to be executed

    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Thank @anthonygood for your hint!

But can someone explain for me why `return false` will not work here? I thought `return false` is the same as using both `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()`?

Comment: `button[0].onclick = submitDataDemo;` should work with `return false;` The event listeners are slightly different from the old `on[event]` function syntax.

Comment: Found the answer! 

- Returning false from an inline event handler prevents the browser from navigating to the link address, but it doesn't stop the event from propagating through the DOM.

- Returning false from a jQuery event handler prevents the browser from navigating to the link address and it stops the event from propagating through the DOM.

- Returning false from a regular DOM event handler does absolutely nothing.